# Unable to install Ubuntu or any other distro on PC

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, 22.04, usb-installation

Windows is installed on following PC, but Linux install fails. I have tried multiple distros, all of the installers have stucked on logo screen.

```
CPU
    Intel Pentium E5200 @ 2.50GHz
    Wolfdale 45nm Technology
RAM
    3,00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 403MHz (6-6-6-18)
Motherboard
    ASUSTeK Computer INC. P5QL/EPU (LGA775)
Graphics
    K-700 (1024x768@85Hz)
    1024MB ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series (Sapphire/PCPartner)
Storage
    465GB SAMSUNG HD502HJ ATA Device (SATA )
Optical Drives
    HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-4167B ATA Device
Audio
    High Definition Audio
```

Comment: Is that machine 32 or 64 bit? s Kubuntu 22.04 a 32-bit?
Kubuntu 22.04 didn't support 32-bit CPU architecture, and is only available to install 64-bit versions.

Comment: A quick scan of https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37212/intel-pentium-processor-e5200-2m-cache-2-50-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html would imply the machine will run *light* systems, but you provided too little detail to allow us to guess at why you are having issues; the largest issues are likely user-procedural actually with no details to disqualify that.

Comment: @guiverc : I couldn't get any error message during installation and unable to see logs. Light, like Lubuntu?

Comment: Lubuntu is the *lightest* flavor of Ubuntu if used *out of the box*  (ie. using the apps provided with the system), but most of us don't use systems *out of the box* but add additional apps we prefer.  As Lubuntu uses LXQt & thus is a Qt5 system, if you wan to use GTK3 apps, you'll get no benefit if contrasted to Xubuntu (using Xfce which is GTK3 based)... ie. apps & desktop should share resources; plus in QA I found Xubuntu outperformed Lubuntu using 5.15 & 5.19 kernels with some hardware (outperforming MATE & others too).  What is *best* for one box & set of apps won't be best for others..

Comment: You've provided no specific details for me to comment on installation, except your detail as provided would imply to me it's procedural errors... ie. you failed to verify your ISO after download; failed to verify the write of ISO to media etc, used an invalid write method for the specific ISO that was used, or used invalid media etc... those are what I consider procedural detail; your lack of detail doesn't rule anything out & they are the largest reasons for issues...

Comment: @guiverc : I have tried the same usb on my notebook and installer is loading perfectly. I tried it with Kubuntu and Linux Mint also. Both of these are OK on my notebook and crashing on that PC.

Comment: **Unless** the notebook you tried has **identical hardware**, that is no guarantee that the USB is perfect as different hardware can cause different parts of the thumb-drive to be read/required, **so unless** you used the other box to validate the media (waited for scan to complete & read the verification done message) another PC with different hardware isn't a valid test; though it is a **very strong indicator** that the media isn't completely wrong **IF** the boot systems on the two are identical. You can write an ISO so it'll boot/work on some boxes but not others so details matter.